# Is it possible to use multiple adwords account to track conversion in an app?

Tags: ios, google-ads-api, conversion-tracking

I have two different adwords account. Can I use both of them in a single app, and track their conversion seperately?

I could not find any specific info at Google.

Thanks,

BR

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'single app', but there is [Google Adwords Manager account](https://adwords.google.com/home/tools/manager-accounts/), where you can see all the accounts you have and [import separate conversions](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/3061730?hl=en) into it and also for ex. report over both.

It's free and here are the [instructions for connecting accounts](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6139186?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea in ios but maybe my answer can give you an opinion. In C# if your two different accounts are under the Manager Account you can use both of them in a single app. First you can add ClientCustomerId (Manager Account Id) in App.config or Web.Config after that you can use *GetAccountHierarchy()*  **(AdWords.Examples.CSharp > v201609 > AccountManagement > GetAccountHierarchy.cs)** function to get all account under Manager Account. You can reach Customer Ids and Customer Names with this function. After you get the Customer Id you can get what data you want with this Customer Ids.

You can check for source code: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-dotnet-lib